# Spark: Compute BSS/TSS from a KmeansModel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

In order to do a measure of the "goodness" of the classification k-means has found I need to calculate the (Between Sum of squares) BSS/TSS  (Total Sum of squares) ratio which should approach 1 if the clustering has the properties of internal cohesion and external separation.  I was wondering whether spark has internal functions to compute BSS/TSS for me similar to the R Kmeans clustering package in order to leverage the parrallism of the spark cluster.

Or is there a cost effective way of computing the BSS/TSS ratio through another means?